# !empty statement not getting the response I anticipated

Tags: php, javascript

I have a call from another page and it is returning photos within a JavaScript slide show, however, I needed to add a message to pop up if there were no photos for that item.I keep getting a error, I am not quite sure what is wrong with my logic..if i add

```
        if(!empty($photo)){
          print '<div class="nophoto">There are no photos for item </div>'; 
    }
```

I will get my message but if i click on a item with photos than the message  will appear for a brief second,when the photos populate the slide show.

```
  <?php
   echo '<div class="container">';
   foreach($value as $photo=>$pictures){
    if(isset($_GET['PhotoVal'])){
      if ($_GET['PhotoVal'] == $photo){
              if(empty($photo)){
             print '<div class="nophoto">There are no photos for this item</div>';
            }
           else
        echo '<div class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">';
      foreach($pictures as $picture){                               
        echo '<li> <img src="photos/'.$picture.'" /></li>' ;         
     }
    echo'</ul></div><a class="close"href="javascript:closeWindow();">Back to Map</a>';
    }
   }
  }

    echo '</div>';
 ?>
```

Comment: If you just run a print_r on $photo what do you return?

Comment: And your elseif statement is within the initial if statement. So when you say "else if" there wasn't an if before it. In order to work the way you intend you need to bring your elseif statement outside of the scope of the parent if statement.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me, if you say `!empty($photo)`, that means 'if $photo is not empty', as in: there _is a photo_. Also `$photo` seems to be the value of an array index, there's almost certainly going to be an index `0`, which is regarded as an empty value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you currently have (with my comments):

```
   echo '<div class="container">';

   foreach($value as $photo=>$pictures){

    if(isset($_GET['PhotoVal'])){ // Successful get? Yes - Continue

      if ($_GET['PhotoVal'] == $photo){ // Variable Assignments do not require an if statement unless you already have $photo set to some value

        echo '<div class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">';

        else if (!empty($photo)){ // You don't need an "else" here and you are actually saying "if photo ISN'T empty" which is the same as saying "if photo DOES have a value". So I don't think that you would want to print "There are no photos for this item" when there is a photo

        print '<div class="nophoto">There are no photos for this item</div>';

      } 
      foreach($pictures as $picture){                               
        echo '<li> <img src="photos/'.$picture.'" /></li>' ;         
     }
    echo'</ul></div><a class="close"href="javascript:closeWindow();">Back to Map</a>';
    }
   }
  }
    echo '</div>';
 ?>
```

What it sounds like you are trying to do:

```
<?php
   echo '<div class="container">'; // Write Container

   foreach($value as $photo=>$pictures){

    if(isset($_GET['PhotoVal'])){ // If we successfully Get PhotoVal proceed

      print 'PhotoVal is set, If you can read this text and there are no images to display then we need to write another if statement within the scope of if(isset($_GET['PhotoVal'])) so we can load placeholder text. If this text doesn't display at all then an else conditional will need to be placed AFTER the if(isset($_GET['PhotoVal'])) statement.';

      $_GET['PhotoVal'] == $photo; // Variable Assignment

      if (empty($photo)) { // If photo is empty write no photo string
          print '<div class="nophoto">There are no photos for this item</div>';
      } else echo '<div class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">';

      foreach($pictures as $picture){

        echo '<li> <img src="photos/'.$picture.'" /></li>' ;         
     }

    echo'</ul></div><a class="close"href="javascript:closeWindow();">Back to Map</a>';

    } else {
          print 'PhotoVal was not set =(';
    }

   }
    echo '</div>'; // Close Container ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Swordfish0321, $photo is a value that i am comparing to PhotoVal. So I need that If statement, if not I would just be ignoring the PhotoVal altogether.

Comment: I have changed the code above and the logic seems correct but I get no error message.. just a blank screen with No echo"No photos for this item"

Comment: Then it sounds like your $photo variable isn't actually empty. If you run print_r($photo); in your script it will tell you what it is ACTUALLY returning. You might need to use NULL depending on what those results are.

Comment: Also I had an error in my example, I accidentally commented out the first curly brace on if (empty($photo)) line. Make sure that isn't commented out (I fixed it in the example).

Comment: Ok this is interesting, If i comment everything out except for the first two lines and do print_r($photo)  after the first foreach I get my expected result (Ex.1234)that item would have 4 photos. Now when i add the next two lines to where I am comparing the get value to photos and do the print_r($photo): i get a blank screen ?

Comment: If you remove the entire if (empty($photo)) chunk of code does it work when there are images? Similarly, does it render blank when there are no photos? I'm just thinking that since you are initially saying "if this isset" that your script is halting before it actually makes it to the empty check.

Comment: Yes so if i remove the empty photo section the code works fine and if a user clicks on a item with no photos a blank screen appears.. All I want to do is have a message with that blank screen saying sorry no photos for this item.. lol I was anticipating a simple if statement

Comment: Ok, this is my last reco, as we can't chat and I actually can't access your code. A crude yet effective way to trace your codes actions is through printing. I would place prints after your conditionals statement eg. after your first if statement print "PhotoVal is set". Do that with all of your logic. This will give you a more visual way of seeing how your code is being interpreted.A simple if statement WILL handle your problem correctly, but it needs to be placed in the correct location. I will update me example to show you what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thank you Swordfish0321 for helping me with my logic